# Subversion pre-commit hook

Tags: linux, svn, hook

Hy!
I have a subversion server running on linux, and I want to set up a hook which checks the format of the log message.
The log message should like this:

#ID TEXT

So it sould start with a # followed by an ID (numbers only) followed by a space and a log message, which is minimun 50 chars length.

How can I do this? Oh, and I want to call some scripts after that and I want to pass the log message to the scripts, so I need the log message in a variable or something.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In a script you get 2 arguments: the first is the repo, the second the transaction. To get more data, learn to use `svnlook` (here: `svnlook log -t $2 $1`). The default templates included in a new repository are pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: if the log message must be 50 chars, you're going to get garbage... people will just type to fill things up even though they don't have much to say.  I think 10 chars be a more realistic number to catch the case that someone simply forgot to enter a message.